# Error in committed chaincode invoke/query with hyperledger fabric 2.0

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I have successfully committed the chaincode with command:

```
./peer lifecycle chaincode commit -o orderer.example.org:7050 --channelID mychannel --name emp_chaincode --version v1 --sequence 1 --init-required --tls --cafile ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.org/orderers/orderer.example.org/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.org-cert.pem
```

Now when I try to invoke/query a the chaincode, I get this error:

```
Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"error in simulation: failed to execute transaction f490a9e7bca41ad10f68306decae2fdd73e09a9d5f81da7c9ee5cdc3811b3f27: invalid invocation: chaincode 'emp_chaincode' has not been initialized for this version, must call as init first"
```

and in chaincode container logs, it shows:

```
+ CHAINCODE_DIR=/usr/local/src

+ cd /usr/local/src

+ npm start -- --peer.address peer0.org1.example.org:7052


> employee@1.0.0 start /usr/local/src

> node emp_chaincode.js "--peer.address" "peer0.org1.example.org:7052"

2020-02-25T09:28:16.743Z info [c-api:lib/chaincode.js] Registering with peer peer0.org1.example.org:7052 as chaincode "emp_chaincodev1:5bcbed31afc58894912eb4c66d63adcec7eab029e2b911887412b119ef5cf319"

2020-02-25T09:28:16.761Z error [c-api:lib/handler.js] Chat stream with peer - on error: %j "Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses\n at Object.exports.createStatusError (/usr/local/src/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:91:15)\n at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/usr/local/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:233:26)\n at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (/usr/local/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:211:8)\n at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/local/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1311:15)\n at InterceptingListener._callNext (/usr/local/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)\n at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/usr/local/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)\n at /usr/local/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1127:18"
```

Please let me know how can I fix it.

**UPDATE:**

After R Thatcher suggested flag addition, error I get now is:

```
Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"error in simulation: failed to execute transaction 038b5c303dfdd98db2c2fc0d2eac6146d7221691cbbed7a78227f5a76a31a240: could not launch chaincode emp_chaincodev1:5bcbed31afc58894912eb4c66d63adcec7eab029e2b911887412b119ef5cf319: chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0"
```

Comment: Please share your commit command.

Comment: @AdityaArora added command in question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right at the end of your error you have **must call as init first**.

I would think that you have used the `peer chaincode lifecycle approveformyorg` command with the flag `--init-required`.  This means that the first invoke of the new chaincode must use the `--isInit` flag e.g. `peer chaincode invoke -C tradechannel -n trade --isInit ...`.  After this first "special" invoke, other invokes and querys will be fine.

Comment: With your update, i get this error: `Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"error in simulation: failed to execute transaction 038b5c303dfdd98db2c2fc0d2eac6146d7221691cbbed7a78227f5a76a31a240: could not launch chaincode emp_chaincodev1:5bcbed31afc58894912eb4c66d63adcec7eab029e2b911887412b119ef5cf319: chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0"`

Comment: The error in the chaincode log `Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect` suggests that there is a networking problem connecting to the peer, or possibly the peer is not started?  How many organisations and peers do you have?

Comment: 2 peers in one organization and they both are running

Comment: I checked that with `goleveldb` everything worked fine, problem seems related to couchdb. @r-thatcher do you have any idea what can be wrong there?

Comment: Actually error was related to docker on Mac, on Ubuntu everything works fine. So your answer solved my problem related to init.